# How to fetch data from java REST API using Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDD0Q.png)http://192.168.0.102:8080/MMBLiveAngular/MMBLive/admin/branch/getdataanjularnoparam

How to fetch data from this api?

Comment: I got this 
Message: Http failure response for http://192.168.0.102:8080/MMBLiveAngular/MMBLive/admin/branch/getdataanjularnoparam: 0 Unknown Error

Comment: sir i got error in browser console  ERROR
HttpErrorResponse {headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://192.168.0.102:8080/MMBLiveAngular/MMBLive/admin/branch/getdataanjularnoparam"…}
error: ProgressEvent
headers: HttpHeaders
message: "Http failure response for http://192.168.0.102:8080/MMBLiveAngular/MMBLive/admin/branch/getdataanjularnoparam: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://192.168.0.102:8080/MMBLiveAngular/MMBLive/admin/branch/getdataanjularnoparam"
__proto__: HttpErrorResponse

Answer (score 1):

You have to use angular HTTP client for this.
Here is [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http) for angular HTTP client.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

this.http
  .get(
    "http://192.168.0.102:8080/MMBLiveAngular/MMBLive/admin/branch/getdataanjularnoparam"
  )
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      console.log("response");
    },
    err => {}
  );
```

Comment: This code won't work, because  `http` is not defined, add the code to get the Http object vid dependency injection as well.

Comment: ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:8896)
    at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)

Comment: add in app.module.ts file :                                                                                          
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';                          
imports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ]

Answer (score 0):

In your component.ts file ,

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project',
  templateUrl: './project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project.component.css']
})

export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {
data:any;
constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://192.168.0.102:8080/MMBLiveAngular/MMBLive/admin/branch/getdataanjularnoparam').subscribe(
        (data:any)=>{
            this.data=data; 
            console.log(data);
        })

   }
```

Now you may use the data variable to access the data from the api.

Comment: ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:8896)
    at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)

Comment: You need to 'import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';'  in app.module.ts

Comment: I have added the code on stackbliz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9knj6j

Comment: sir  console show this error    ERROR
HttpErrorResponse {headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://192.168.0.102:8080/MMBLiveAngular/MMBLive/admin/branch/getdataanjularnoparam"…}
error: ProgressEvent
headers: HttpHeaders
message: "Http failure response for http://192.168.0.102:8080/MMBLiveAngular/MMBLive/admin/branch/getdataanjularnoparam: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://192.168.0.102:8080/MMBLiveAngular/MMBLive/admin/branch/getdataanjularnoparam"

Comment: That is because 192.168.0.102 is a local ip address. We will not be able to access data from local ip address using a public ip address. Copy the code to your project and it should show you the data.

Comment: Can you check using POSTMAN if the api is working fine and you are getting the required data

Comment: yes sir i check in POSTMAN  but i dont know how to use it in angular

Comment: Have you got a correct response using POSTMAN? Can you share the screenshot  of postman screenshot?

Comment: what are the parameters that you pass to the api